# How to transpose specific columns based on a condition in python 2.7

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data format in a file:

```
ID,var_name,var_value
1,ABC,This is abc1
1,DEF,This is def1
2,ABC,This is abc2
2,DEF,This is def2
2,GHI,This is ghi2
3,ABC,This is abc3
4,ABC,This is abc4
4,DEF,This is def4
```

also I have a header list = `['ABC','GHI']`

In the above data set each "ID" will not necessarily have all the variables, however `ID:2` contains the maximum number of variables (ABC,DEF,GHI). I need to convert the above dataset to the following nested list format:

```
[['ID','ABC','GHI'], [1,'This is abc1', ''],[2, 'This is abc2','This is ghi2'],[3,'This is abc3',''],[4,'This is abc4','']]
```

That means the list should:

- populate the data for all the IDs
- create null string for those variables which are not present in the above dataset.
- populate the nested list, maintaining the same order as the Header list
- populate only those header value i.e. the header list only has values 'ABC','GHI' so the nested list should only populate the values 'ABC' and 'GHI', and should ignore 'DEF' rows from the above dataset.

I want to do this in Python 2.7, possibly using Pandas.

Comment: (pandas is the package for dataframes. anaconda is not a package, it's an installer)

Comment: There seems to be a lot of tactical downvoting on this question; two answers are +1/-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
L = ['ABC','GHI']

df1 = df.pivot('ID', 'var_name', 'var_value').fillna('')[L].reset_index()
print (df1)
var_name  ID           ABC           GHI
0          1  This is abc1              
1          2  This is abc2  This is ghi2
2          3  This is abc3              
3          4  This is abc4     

L1 = [df1.columns.tolist()] + df1.values.tolist()
print (L1)

[['ID', 'ABC', 'GHI'], 
 [1, 'This is abc1', ''], 
 [2, 'This is abc2', 'This is ghi2'],
 [3, 'This is abc3', ''], 
 [4, 'This is abc4', '']]
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), replace `NaN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html),  convert subset for filtering columns and create column from index by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
2. Last create nested list and last insert columns names

EDIT:

I try change order of values in list:

```
L = ['GHI', 'ABC']
df1 = df.pivot('ID', 'var_name', 'var_value').fillna('')[L].reset_index()
print (df1)
var_name  ID           GHI           ABC
0          1                This is abc1
1          2  This is ghi2  This is abc2
2          3                This is abc3
3          4                This is abc4

L1 = [df1.columns.tolist()] + df1.values.tolist()
print (L1)

[['ID', 'GHI', 'ABC'],
 [1, '', 'This is abc1'], 
 [2, 'This is ghi2', 'This is abc2'], 
 [3, '', 'This is abc3'], 
 [4, '', 'This is abc4']]
```

Comment: @KenT - I last remove filtering, because there is possible some rows should be removed, what should be really bad :)

Comment: @KenT - In my opinion you cannot use drop, because need filter by list

Comment: This works fine for me. only one thing when I am reordering the values of L=['GHI','ABC'] the the first row of L1 is still ['ID', 'ABC', 'GHI'] it should be ['ID', 'GHI','ABC']

Comment: Sorry, give me a sec.

Comment: @SourajitRoyChowdhury - I try solution with change order and for me it working, can you check edited answer?

Comment: @jezrael I need one more help, is there any way to do the same thing if the header (ID,var_name,var_value) is not present in my file only other rows are present, but in the file it should be in the same sequence as the header.

Comment: @SourajitRoyChowdhury - Yes, it is possible. What is `print(df.columns)` ? I understand it there are not columns names `'ID', 'var_name', 'var_value'` ?

Comment: @jezrael Yes, you are right. But if I changed that as well, then our solutions will be exactly the same. I will just keep my answer the same as an alternative for those who may find it useful.

Comment: Yes it is working even without the header. @jezrael say in my case i have given there is one 'ID' but if in my csv file there are two tow ids (ID1 and ID2) and this combination makes the actual ID then how to pass it to the pivot method?

Comment: @SourajitRoyChowdhury - I think `pivot` cannot working with it, need `f = df.set_index(['ID1','ID2', 'var_name'])['var_value'].unstack(fill_value='')[L].reset_index()`

Comment: That woked :) so is there any thing for multiple values like var_value1 & var_value2?

Comment: @SourajitRoyChowdhury - more complicated, I think the best is create new question with sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to stay in this beautiful panda's dataframe

```
df2=(df.pivot(index='ID', columns='var_name', values='var_value')
     .fillna('').drop('DEF', axis=1).reset_index())



#output:
var_name  ID           ABC           GHI
0          1  This is abc1              
1          2  This is abc2  This is ghi2
2          3  This is abc3              
3          4  This is abc4
```

But also you can do further to acheive the list:

```
print([df2.columns.tolist()] + df2.values.tolist())

[['ID', 'ABC', 'GHI'], 
[1, 'This is abc1', ''], 
[2, 'This is abc2', 'This is ghi2'], 
[3, 'This is abc3', ''], 
[4, 'This is abc4', '']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can just set a `multiindex` and `unstack`:

```
In []:
L = ['ABC', 'GHI']
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'var_name'])['var_value'].unstack(fill_value='')[L].reset_index()
df

Out[]:
var_name  ID           ABC           GHI
0          1  This is abc1              
1          2  This is abc2  This is ghi2
2          3  This is abc3              
3          4  This is abc4              

In []:
[df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()

Out[]:
[['ID', 'ABC', 'GHI'],
 [1, 'This is abc1', ''],
 [2, 'This is abc2', 'This is ghi2'],
 [3, 'This is abc3', ''],
 [4, 'This is abc4', '']]
```